# Inputting strings into an array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I would like to input the gathered strings from a scanner, then put them into a String[] the problem i'm having is I cant find a way to input them in a few statements. I don't want to have any loops, because I do not want to have the message asking for a name to repeat 20 times over. I want to take 20 names typed in with a space in-between each name to go into 20 different spaces in an array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Gradebook {
String[] lastName;
String[] firstName;
int[] ID;
int[][] testGrades;
int[][] hwGrades;
    public Gradebook(String[] lastName, String[] firstName, int[] ID, int[][] testGrades, int[][] hwGrades){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.lastName = new String[20];
        this.firstName = new String[20];
        this.ID = new int[20];
        this.testGrades = new int[20][5];
        this.hwGrades = new int[20][5];
            System.out.println("Enter last names of all people in alphbetical order: ");
            // this was my attempt to input them: 
         lastName[] = input.next();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be read the string as whole with spaces and later spilt from spaces as follows:

```
String input="asd asd";
String result[]=input.split("\\s+");
```

**Output :**

```
output for specified input 'asd asd'
asd
asd
```

Your input string would contain words separated with spaces.

Comment: An even better way would be to use a StringBuilder

Comment: @EvanBechtol, I'm not sure why it would matter in this particular case, but I +1'd your comment because I do agree that using StringBuilder by default is a great habit to get into.  If you find yourself trying to do anything but the most trivial of things with String, then StringBuilder is your man.  And it's a much cleaner approach than StringBuffer was.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question clearly but here's some code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] names = (in.nextLine()).split(" ");

 /* an input such as the following:
    this is an example

   would result in the following:
   names[] = {"this", "is", "an", "example"}; */
   }
}
```